# How to get first and last name from an email address

Tags: apex

I am trying to get the first and last name from email address field in Apex code but I am only getting the first name not able to get the last name can anyone please help me.

For an example 
First.last@abc.com

I need to get a string which will be having "First last"

Thanks

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: This only works where you have a naming convention used in the email of First.last@domain.com - it will break with anything like FirstLast@domain.com or Initial.Last@domain.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your requirement is to substring the left part before the `@` and then split this substring using the `.` character, you can easily do this with the [String class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm).

```
String leftPart = email.substringBefore('@');
String[] leftPartSplitted = leftPart.split('\\.');
//we check if there's one dot in the substring
if(leftPartSplitted.size() == 2){
   String firstName = leftPartSplitted[0];
   String lastName = leftPartSplitted[1];
}else{
   //there is no dot or more than one dot in the substring
}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

You Have to know that your emailid and your account name for that email id can be different.

ex -

```
Name - William James Chadwick Potter
     email - William123@gamil.com
  {First Name}+{Last Name} - {William} + {James Chadwick Potter}
                           - {William James} + {Chadwick Potter}
                           - {William James Chadwick} + {Potter}
```

Your Logic wont work here

Comment: That might be the case for personal email, but professional office emails are always firestname + lastname

Comment: Not all professional names are first and last. I already had emails like first word from first name + lastname. Also, when you have two people with the same first and last name. Like, Maria Silva in countries that speaks Portuguese... It could be solved adding a number